# Embedding Unity into Swift Project : No such module 'UnityFramework'

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

```swift
import Foundation
import UnityFramework

class Unity: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    static let shared = Unity()

    private let dataBundleId: String = "com.unity3d.framework"
    private let frameworkPath: String = "/Frameworks/UnityFramework"

    private var ufw : UnityFramework?
    private var hostMainWindow : UIWindow?

    private var isInitialized: Bool {
        ufw?.appController() != nil
    }

    func show() {
        if isInitialized {
            showWindow()
        } else {
            initWindow()
        }
    }

    func setHostMainWindow(_ hostMainWindow: UIWindow?) {
        self.hostMainWindow = hostMainWindow
    }
```

> No such module 'UnityFramework'

Anyway even already

[image]

Please help and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build in the simulator or in a real device?

By default on the Player Settings in Unity the Unity project is exported to be run in a real device for arm64 architecture. You can change it to SDKSimulator for x86 architecture. For the moment there is no support for arm64 in SDKSimulator.